# Angular: how to prevent default router event

Tags: angular, router, preventdefault

In my app component I'm checking if there are any open modals while the route is changing. In that case, I want to

- close the open modals
- prevent route change because for a user the closing of the modal is already a route change...

I've succeeded in closing the modals if there is one open, but I cannot find a way to use something like 'event.preventDefault()'

```js
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      private routerEventSubscription : Subscription;
      
      constructor (
        private router: Router,
        private modalService: NgbModal
      ) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.routerEventSubscription = this.router.events.pipe(
          filter( event => event instanceof NavigationStart ),
          pairwise()
        ).subscribe( event => {
          console.log(event);
          if (this.modalService.hasOpenModals()) {
            this.modalService.dismissAll();
            /***  ==> Here I want to prevent the route from changing <== ***/
          }
        })
      }
      
      ngOnDestroy () {
        this.routerEventSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The router events will not help you in preventing the navigation as they are simply a mean to let you know what is happening, for preventing the user to leave the current route they're in you need to use the `canDeactivate` property of routes.

You can check the official documentation here: https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

And you can find examples/explanations online like this one: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-candeactivate-guard-example

Basically you create a guard which implements the `CanDeactivate` interface and assign that guard to all the routes in your application which you want to user to leave and implement the logic you need in the guard itself (you get the current component and can use that to implement your logic, or you can even ignore it and use some shared service or anything you want).

Comment: This is an option indeed. But I was hoping there is a more generic solution which is applied to all routes without needing to add a guard to every route...

Comment: Yes I understand. But I think you do need to configure the routes in order to let Angular know how to behave and I don't think this can be done on the module level as you usually would not want to implement the same to all routers I think. Anyways I did not try that but I would imagine that `CanDeactivate` applied to a route also applies to all its children, so if you put all your routes as the app's children you can then set the `canDeactivate` option to just that one. I think that that would work but I can't be 100% sure since I haven't tried, may be worth giving it a try if you want :)